# How to elicit prediction intervals from clients?

Tags: prediction-interval, highest-density-region, elicitation, consulting

When I prepare probabilistic forecasts I am often left with a choice of what percentage highest-density region to choose for prediction intervals for clients. This matters for reporting uncertainty to the clients, but I think for many of them it is a difficult abstraction.

I feel like the elicitation should contain these components:

1. Explain what a prediction interval is (in non-technical language).
2. Explain what prediction intervals are for.
3. Give an example of using a prediction interval.
4. Suggest some factors to consider in choosing prediction intervals.
5. Ask what percentage would be preferable.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to help clients understand step 4.